# Spatio-temporal version of Hammersley and Clifford theorem

Tags: probability, spatio-temporal

Does anybody encountered or derived a spatiotemporal version of Hammersley and Clifford theorem? The original theorem (with the proof by Besag) fits just for the temporal models, but if I have a sample of data, that was collected at different times in the same locations, than I need also to incorporate a temporal effect, but still no luck to find any appropriate literature.